# wxPython: Is there a control that will allow you to hide windows?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

What I am looking for is a control or option that I can use slide sections of my GUI in and out of view.  Im considering using different tabs to do this, but that would mean I would have 16 tabs, and I don't like the way it looks.

What I have in mind is a series of labels down the right side of my gui.  A click on each label would slide out (or in) the info about that label while leaving the persistent part of the gui still visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of other "book" controls that might fit your need. Try the Listbook or the Toolbook controls. There are examples in the wxPython demo or you can try http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/2/ or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/3/

Comment: On your examples you use 'import panelOne'  I get an import error on that line.  Is there something I have to do to make that bit work?

Comment: Yeah, there's a code bundle that you need to download at the end of the article. Sorry about that.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I really like the AUI, im going to give that a shot.

Comment: It didn't do exactly what I wanted - but it gave me a good answer to go in another direction

Comment: FYI: There are two AUI widgets. The one in wx.aui and another in wx.lib.agw. The latter is written in pure Python.